# Least squares: How does the projection theorem lead to the normal equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I understand why $\vec{{P}}$ (the orthogonal projection of $\vec{{b}}$ on **w**)
is the closest vector to $\vec{{b}}$ (The vector that does not give us a solution to the 
equation and that's why we need to do the process)

But I do not understand the equation:
$$A^TA\vec{{x}}=A^T \vec{{b}}$$
Why does multiplying each side of the original equation $A\vec{{x}}=\vec{{b}}$ (We know she has no answer)
by $A^T$ give us the closest answer?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given vector $\vec b$ and matrix $A$, the goal is to find $\vec x$ so that $A\vec x$ is as close to $\vec b$ as possible.

Let $W$ be the subspace of all vectors of the form $A\vec x$. Observe that $W$ is the set of all linear combinations of columns of $A$.

We are looking for the vector in $W$ that is closest to $\vec b$. Write $A\hat x$ for this vector. By the projection theorem, $A\hat x$ is the orthogonal projection of $\vec b$ onto $W$. Equivalently, $A\hat x-\vec b$ is orthogonal to every vector in $W$. As a special case, we conclude:

$$
\text{$A\hat x-\vec b$ is orthogonal to every column of matrix $A$}.
\tag{*}$$

Constraint (*) can be written in matrix form as:
$$ A^T(A\hat x-b) = 0,$$ which leads to the equation $A^TA\hat x=A^T\vec b$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. i just do not understand how it helps us if: $$ A^T(A\hat x-b) = 0,$$  Is a multiplication of each column of A Gives us a solution because the multiplication is equal to 0?

Comment: @NFLX You can rewrite the matrix equation $A^T(A\hat x-b)=0$ into a system of linear equations that can be solved for the best $\hat x$. In other words, the projection theorem leads to conditions that the best $\hat x$ must satisfy. These conditions lead to an equation that we can solve.

Comment: (Sorry it's long)
I kind of explain everything to myself and just tell me if I'm right:
We are looking for the vector which is closest to $\vec{{b}}$ because $\vec{{b}}$
Is not a solution to $$A\vec{{x}}=\vec{{b}}$$.
We know that $\vec{{P}}$ (the Orthogonal projection is the closest solution.
So we demand that $$ A^T(\vec{{P}}-\vec{{B}}) = 0,$$
Because it tells us it's 90 degrees between $\vec{{P}}$ and $\vec{{B-P}}$ 
and that it proves to us that $\vec{{P}}$ is the closest?

Comment: @NFLX Yes,  $\vec u^T\vec v=0$ means the vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are orthogonal. And if $\vec P$ is the vector in $W$ that is closest to $\vec b$ then the projection theorem states that the error vector $\vec b-\vec P$ is orthogonal to every vector in $W$.

Comment: Excellent!
really really thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment, but my answer to: [How to formulate ordinary least squares regression in component formalism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900895/how-to-formulate-ordinary-least-squares-regression-in-component-formalism/3903564#3903564) may address your question. The reason multiplying each side by $A^T$ helps is that while $A$ may not have an inverse, $A^TA$ typically does, allowing you to solve for $\vec{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

@nosuchthingasmagic gives a link to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900895/how-to-formulate-ordinary-least-squares-regression-in-component-formalism/3903564#3903564) that gives a calculus-based derivation. Here's [another one](https://are.berkeley.edu/courses/EEP118/current/derive_ols.pdf).

The standard notation is $\vec y = X \vec {\beta}$. Then we note that this has no exact solution, so really $X \vec {\beta} = \vec y + \vec {\epsilon}$. If $\vec \beta$ is optimal, then $X^T \vec {\epsilon}=\vec 0$. So when we multiply both sides by $X$, $\epsilon$ disappears and we're left with $X^TX \vec {\beta} = X^T\vec y$.

Why $X^T \vec {\epsilon}=\vec 0$? Well, that's saying that every row of $X^T$ is orthogonal to $\vec {\epsilon}$. And the rows of $X^T$ represent all the observations of a particular feature. So this is saying that for each feature, the observations of that feature are uncorrelated with the errors. If there were a correlation, we could adjust the corresponding $\beta_i$ to get a better fit.